# Horas en JDateChooser

Tags: java

Tengo 2 JDateChooser, cuando hago JDateChooser1.getDate me regresa la fecha seleccionada con hora `00:00:00`

Cuando hago JDateChooser2.getDate me regresa la fecha seleccionada con la hora en que se hizo la selección.

Necesito que ambos JDateChooser me regresen la hora `00:00:00`.

Anexo código, nunca entra al `else` del `if`, porque las fechas nunca son iguales por la diferencia de horas a la hora de hacer la elección de fecha.

```
public void llenaCalendarioTarifas(){
    String consulta = "Insert into calendario tarifas (fecha, id_tarifa, id_tipoCuarto) values ";
    String fecha = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(dateInicio.getDate());
    String fechaF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(dateFinal.getDate());
    String idTarifa ="5";
    Date fInicio = dateInicio.getDate();
    Date fFinal = dateFinal.getDate();
    Calendar cal= Calendar.getInstance();

    while(fInicio.compareTo(fFinal)<= 0){

        if(fInicio.compareTo(fFinal)== -1){
            consulta = consulta + "\n('" + fecha + "', " + idTarifa + ", " + idTipo + "), ";
           // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, consulta);
        }else {
            consulta = consulta + "\n('" + fecha + "', " + idTarifa + ", " + idTipo + ")";
           // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, consulta);
        }
        cal.setTime(fInicio);
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        fInicio = cal.getTime();
        fecha = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(fInicio);
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, consulta);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Podrías intentar esto...

Fecha:

```
String formato = "dd/MM/yyyy";
Date date = JFecha.getDate();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(formato);
lblfecha.setText(sdf.format(date));
```

Hora:

```
String dia = Integer.toString(jdt.getCalendar().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
String mes = Integer.toString(jdt.getCalendar().get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
String year = Integer.toString(jdt.getCalendar().get(Calendar.YEAR));
String fecha = (year + "-" + mes+ "-" + dia);
txtfecha.setText(fecha);
```

El ejemplo que has puesto en tu pregunta lo he encontrado muy largo y complicado para hacer algo tan simple. He hecho un pequeño programa con este ejercicio y funciona a la perfección. Sigo sin entender de dónde tu obtienes la hora del sistema, en mi caso no pasa.

Aquí un ejemplo funcional para obtener solamente las fechas y saber la diferencia en días que hay entre ambas:

```
    // Indicamos que solo puede ingresar numeros, año/mes/día
    // y en el campo de texto se mostrará este patron "____/__/__"
    // mientras no ingrese o seleccione una fecha
    JDateChooser dateChooser1 = new JDateChooser("yyyy-MM-dd", "####-##-##", '_');
    dateChooser1.setBounds(12, 60, 195, 22);
    contentPane.add(dateChooser1);
    
    JDateChooser dateChooser2 = new JDateChooser("yyyy-MM-dd", "####-##-##", '_');
    dateChooser2.setBounds(225, 60, 195, 22);
    contentPane.add(dateChooser2);
    
    JButton btnComparar = new JButton("Comparar");
    btnComparar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // Formato
            SimpleDateFormat dcn = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            // Obtener fechas seleccionadas tipo String
            String date1 = dcn.format(dateChooser1.getDate());
            String date2 = dcn.format(dateChooser2.getDate());
            // Imprimir
            System.out.println("Fecha 1: " + date1);
            System.out.println("Fecha 2: " + date2);

            // Obtener la diferencia en milisegundos
            long diffMillis = dateChooser1.getDate().getTime() - dateChooser2.getDate().getTime();
            // Transformar milisegundos a días
            long diffDays = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diffMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            // Imprimir
            System.out.println("Diferencia: " + diffDays + " días");
        }
    });
    btnComparar.setBounds(12, 109, 408, 43);
    contentPane.add(btnComparar);
```

Luego, como tu utilizas `if-else` para hacer algo, podrías usar la variable `diffDays` para hacer la comparación. Si es mayor a X días, haz esto, si no, haz lo otro...

Output:

> Fecha 1: 2018-03-31
>
> Fecha 2: 2018-03-01
>
> Diferencia: 29 días

Comment: Hola Robert, para presentar la fecha no tengo problemas, el problema radica en que debo comparar las fechas de ambos JDateChooser, y en cierto momento necesito que sean iguales, el problema es que al tomar horas diferentes a la hora de hacer la selección, eso nunca ocurre, lo que quiero saber es cómo manipular la hora que toma el valor date cuando hago la selección en el JDateChooser. Gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder.

Comment: Obteniendo solo la fecha (no horas) podrías hacer las comparaciones que indicas. Si esto no te funciona, podrías editar tu pregunta con el código que estás usando y podremos ayudarte a buscar una solución.

Comment: Hola de nuevo Robert, justo eso es lo que necesito y no encuentro como hacerlo, edité la pregunta con el código para que puedas revisarlo, la idea es crear un query, donde se agrega un registro por cada día seleccionado, barriendo desde la fecha de inicio a la fecha de final, cuando las fechas sean iguales, debería entrar al else, pero por la diferencia de horas nunca entra.

Comment: @GeorgeMaldonado He editado mi respuesta con otra respuesta con un ejemplo funcionando, espero que te ayude.